# Specified cast is not valid casting a SqlParameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

This code gives  an InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

```
// getting the user id

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("getId", conn);
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", email));

// output parm
SqlParameter user_id = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@user_id", SqlDbType.Int);
count.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

Session["user_id"] = user_id;

Response.Redirect("~/CheckProfile.aspx");
```

And then when using this user_id in another page, I write this:

```
int user_id = (int)(Session["user_id"]);
```

Comment: `SqlParameter` != `int`

Comment: Use `AddWithValue()` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You're storing `SqlParameter` in Session["user_id"] and then attempting to cast that to `int`. That cast cannot be done.

Instead do:

```
Session["user_id"] = (int)user_id.Value;
```

Then you will have stored the `int`, and be able to retrieve it as such. You may though want to cast to `int?` because then you can deal with it not having been set:

```
int? userIDMaybe = (int?)Session["user_id"];
if(userIDMaybe.HasValue)
{
  int userID = userIDMaybe.Value;
  /* ... */
}
else
{
  /* Code to handle not logged in yet... */
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, pointing to this line of code :            Session["user_id"] = (int)(user_id.Value);    any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("getId", conn);
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", email));

// output parm
SqlParameter user_id = new SqlParameter("@user_id", SqlDbType.Int);
user_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd2.Parameters.Add(user_id);

conn.Open();
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

Session["user_id"] = cmd2.Parameters["@user_id"].Value;

Response.Redirect("~/CheckProfile.aspx");
```